# Support of two authentication modes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Currently I have a site with usual authentication mode: login/password. The new authentication mode must be added (some number which will be verified by another system, an answer will be returned and a user will be logged in or not). So I have to store this number in my DB in addition to login/password data. 
User can upgrade his/her account to use the new authentication mode, but after this the old one will not be available anymore. Only the new one will be used for the registration of new accounts.

Could you please suggest the best way to handle this situation? The simplest way in my opinion it's just save this new code in some additional property and check if this property empty or not (or add some enumeration LoginType with corresponding values).

UPDATE:
I'm wondering whether can i just use the provided above way to solve the problem or it will be a bad workaround? Also (as the second approach) I thinking about removing the current record (user account) and adding a new one with the new login name on account upgrade (when user changes the way to log in). Now I use *DefaultMembershipProvider*.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Question related to ASP.NET (Web forms), not ASP.NET MVC.

Maxim

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Please clarify your question by adding any implementations/patterns you've attempted.

Comment: Also, what ASP.NET framework are you using? MVC?